# Change font style inline in wx.TextCtrl and wx.StaticText

Tags: python, wxpython, wizard

I am using wxPython to build a wizard with PyWizardPages.

I'm wondering if there's a way to bold or italicize text "inline"?

In other words:

```
# StaticText
a = wx.StaticText(page, -1, "Click Next")

# TextCtrl
b = wx.TextCtrl(page2, -1, "")
b.SetValue("Here are the details:")
```

Now, say, I want to bold the "Next" and italicize "details."  This is not kosher syntax but just something that I'd like to be able to do, if possible:

```
# Hypothetical way to inline bold
a = wx.StaticText(page, -1, "Click <b>Next</b>")

# Hypothetical way to inline italicize
b.SetValue("Here are the <i>details</i>:")
```

Is something like this possible or do I need to create a new StaticText/TextCtrl, bold and italicize them, and then figure out how to place it accordingly in the grid so it looks like it's one whole sentence?

Comment: I think you want the RichText style ... there is also a RichText widget, as well as an HTML renderer thing

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yes, I think that seems to be what I want.  I took a look at the RichText widget but I can't figure what you mean by the RichText style, though.  Not sure which would be easier for me to implement since I'm starting with `StaticText` and `TextCtrl`.  Also, if you right write response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TextCtrl has a style flag called wx.TE_RICH and wx.TE_RICH2. Both of these are shown in the wxPython demo. I don't believe the StaticText widget will work for you. There is also a RichText widget that you could use or a StyleTextCtrl. Another alternative would be to draw the text onscreen yourself, which would give you the most control. There are examples of all of these topic in the wxPython demo, so I would start there.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you. I added the `wx.TE_RICH` style to TextCtrl and was able to bold and italicize parts of the TextCtrl that I needed.  I still haven't quite figured out how to do that for StaticText yet though.  I'll look into RichText.